# can a logrotate config point to a directory

Tags: apache, config, logrotate, log-rotation

Primary question: Is it a valid option in a logrotate config to have the targeted log be a directory?

I have seen several examples using the wildcard notation of  `/var/log/example/*.log`, but I am curious if the option of `/var/log/example` will give a similar result.

I checked the [man pages](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html), but only found examples with the wildcard syntax. This led me to believe that was the only way. However, there is a sentence in the doc which reads, "The last section defines  the  parameters  for  all  of  the  files  in /var/log/news" in reference to an example without a wildcard, which caused me to question.

Background of question:
In dealing with the [logrotate recipe](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apache2/blob/master/recipes/logrotate.rb) (from the apache2 community cookbook) which is intended to setup logrotation for the httpd install, the created config points to a directory. `logrotate -d` shows that an operation is being performed (I think), but none of the files contained in the directory are being rotated on `logrotate -f`. Since obviously I am unfamiliar with logrotate I was hoping someone could enlighten me (before I log a ticket / pull request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do note that the example they use shows /var/log/news/*, so I'm pretty sure /var/log/news/ will not do anything for you.  As I've noted in another thread, you can run logrotate with the '-d' flag and it will not perform any rotations, but will show you what it WOULD do for a particular configuration file.